# TypeMismatchError in drawImage()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm using `drawImage()`. This is my code. `imDiv` holds an inline svg.

```
  var c =document.getElementById( 'cvs' );
  var ctx =c.getContext( '2d' );
  var img =document.getElementById( 'imDiv' );
   ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );  //TypeMismatchError
```

I'm getting a `TypeMismatchError` error. What might be the reason and How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is `imDiv` the id of a div that contains an image? If so, this wont work - you need to supply the image element itself, rather than the div that contains it. Even if the div has the `background-image` attribute set, passing a div element still wont work. You can only pass an `img` element or a `canvas` element as the first parameter to `ctx.drawImage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must convert the SVG to an image first, then draw the image to canvas.

There are some things you need to take into consideration:

- The SVG must be well-formed (think XML)
- The first element in the SVG must be xmlns attributed
- There are variable security restrictions depending on browser when it comes to `foreignObject` (to embed HTML etc.). It will work in some (Firefox, without external references), others not so much (f.ex. Chrome). This is currently in a state of vacuum, and we can't do much about it on client side

## Here is one way of doing this:

```js
// Inline SVG:
var svg = document.querySelector('svg').outerHTML,  // make sure SVG tags are included
  canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),        // target canvas
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// convert to image (see function below)
// converting to image is an asynchronous process, so we need a callback
svgToImage(svg, function(img) {

  // HERE you could insert the image to DOM:
  // var myElement = document.getElementById(elementID);
  // myElement.appendChild(img);
  
  // set canvas size = image
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;

  // draw SVG-image to canvas
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
});

// this will convert an inline SVG to a DATA-URI
function svgToImage(svg, callback) {
  var url = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(svg),
      img = new Image;

  // handle image loading, when done invoke callback
  img.onload = function() {
    callback(this);
  };

  img.src = url;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100">
  <linearGradient id="gradient">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#00f" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f70" />
  </linearGradient>
  <rect fill="url(#gradient)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>

<br>
<canvas></canvas><br>
```

Comment: thanks... that's truly great. I'm having a little issue because there are multiple svgs on page. So I tried replacing `svg = document.querySelector('svg').outerHTML,'` and `canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),`  to  `var canvas = document.getElementById( 'cvs' ),` and `svg = document.getElementById( 'imDiv' )`.  When I did this the `url` output is something like this `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%5object%20HTMLDivElement%5D`. So how do I target a specific svg by it's container DIV and also how do I target the draw canvas by it's ID?

Comment: @user3687622 you have to use the outerHTML to get the string content, for example: `svg = document.getElementById('cvs').outerHTML;`. The outerHTML included the outer tags for the element you target (ie. `<svg ...>...</svg>`). If you don't use it you will only get the element *object* itself which can't be used as string.

Comment: I was just looking at your undo-redo js plugin - that's really nice. :)

Comment: Just another quick question. What does `img` refered to? How do I draw it in a specific canvas? E.g.: `var img =document.getElementById( 'imDiv' );` and use `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);`

Comment: @user3687622 img is the image element created inside svgToImage. In the callback the same img name is used. You can store this to a global value and use it from there if you want. It is also possible to insert it directly into DOM by using someElement.appendChild(img), but in that case I would recommend setting an ID first (img.id = "img1"; ...appendChild(img)). But since you need to handle it asynchronous in any case, it's best to do it from inside the callback function.

Comment: I tried this but something seems to be wrong. The image is not drawing/showing? `var imgR =document.getElementById( 'imDiv' );` `imgR.appendChild(img);`

Comment: @user3687622 do you get any errors in console? let me update with a comment inside the handler on how you can add the image..

Comment: The `img.onload = function() { };` dosen't work. Replacing `img.onload = function() {  callback(this); };` with `callback(img);` works BUT how do I make the `onload()` work? Also why does the drawn image disappear? I'm able to see the drawen image if I add an alert after `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);` but as soon as the alert is closed the drawn image disappears? I've included `var myElement = document.getElementById('imDiv'); myElement.appendChild(img);` as suggested in your recent edit. The drawn image is shown even if I remove `myElement.appendChild(img);`. No errors shown.

Comment: @user3687622 I believe this is out of scope for this question. I would suggest open a new question. It's pretty straight forward as shown in the answer. In the new question you could include the code you have problems with.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, it's impossible to draw `div` or `svg` elements onto the canvas. The first argument passed to `context.drawImage()` must be an `Image`, canvas, or even a video element (using the svg is probably causing the `TypeMismatchError`).

So you'll have retrieve an actual `Image` on the document with `getElementById()` or create one with `new Image()`.