# DrawImage on a dynamically created canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

First off [see this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z769z7af/2/)

I want to create a canvas on the fly and append it to a particular DIV and draw an inline svg onto the canvas. But does not work as expected.

```
var randn = '1';

    function createme(){
        alert("completed 0");
          var crCavs = $('<canvas />',{ id : 'mycanvs'+randn })

          $('#album').append(crCavs);
        alert("completed 1");

          var svg2 =document.getElementById('sVgsource'+randn).outerHTML,
              vms =document.getElementById('mycanvs'+randn), // target canvas
              ctx2 =vms.getContext('2d');

          //callback
          svgToImage(svg2, function(img2){
            vms.width =$('#sVgsource'+randn).width();
            vms.height =$('#sVgsource'+randn).height();
            alert("completed 3");
            ctx2.drawImage(img2, 30, 40);
              alert("completed 4");
          }

          function svgToImage(svg2, callback) {
            var nurl = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + encodeURIComponent(svg2),
                img2 = new Image;
            //invoke callback
              callback(img2);

              img2.src = nurl;
              alert("completed 2");
          }
    }
    createme();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an end-parenthesis for the `svgToImage()` function:

```
svgToImage(svg2, function(img2) {
    vms.width = img2.width;
    vms.height = img2.height;
    alert("completed 3");
    ctx2.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
      alert("completed 4");
}); // <-- here
```

There are also some other issues:

Just reuse the canvas element:

```
var canvCrtrWrp = $('<canvas />',{ id : 'mycanvs'+randn })

...
var vms = canvCrtrWrp[0];  // index 0 is the actual canvas element
```

You could also use the width from the produced image on the canvas:

```
svgToImage(svg2, function(img2) {
    vms.width = img2.width;
    vms.height = img2.height;
    ...
```

Remember to use the `onload` handler for image (it was removed from the original code).If not an image element is passed back without any actual image data (need some time to load, decode etc.):

```
 function svgToImage(svg2, callback) {
     var nurl = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(svg2),
         img2 = new Image;

     img2.onload = function() {
        callback(this);
     }
     ...
```

etc.

Updated **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/z769z7af/7/)**.

Comment: thanks. See https://jsfiddle.net/z769z7af/5/ Why does the canvas disappear after `alert("completed 1")`?

Comment: I adjusted the height and width of the canvas so the canvas stop disappearing. See https://jsfiddle.net/z769z7af/6/ But I have no idea why the `drawImage();` is not working? Nothing appears to be on the canvas? Perhaps this question might be related to my previous comment too?? Is there something missing in the callback function?

Comment: @Beki you had onload handler removed for image. https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/z769z7af/7/

Comment: thanks/ I tried that too but adding the onload handler does not fix the issue. As in your fiddle it shows only the background color. the canvas is empty.

Comment: @Beki http://i.imgur.com/Ahh3vuS.png I'm not gonna do more debugging for you :) If you follow carefully you should be be able to use the code provided to fix the problem. Or go back to the original code and start over: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29369403/typemismatcherror-in-drawimage/29380101#29380101

Comment: :) got it working. But Doesn't work in IE. Why is that? How can I fox it?