# "Unhandled promise rejection TypeMismatchError" in internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-11, potrace

I am using a port for javascript bases on potrace: https://github.com/kilobtye/potrace
this library converts images to svg
Everything works except for(ofcourse...) internet explorer 11.
i get the error: "Unhandled promise rejection TypeMismatchError"

There is hardly anything that can be found about this library so i would hope any of you code guru's could help me out.

Here is the code i use:
value is a base64 string of a image

```
    static changeLogo(value) {
        $("#svg-image svg, #svg-image svg").empty();
        Potrace.loadImageFromUrl(value);
        Potrace.process(function () {
            let svgImage = Potrace.getSVG(1);
            $("#svg-image").append(svgImage);
        })
    }
```

Comment: please check this [Elegant way to include es6-promise for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45509701/elegant-way-to-include-es6-promise-for-ie)

Comment: Hum not very clear from the source code but my guess is that it is related to the `loadImageFromUrl` function. Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29369403/typemismatcherror-in-drawimage. In the source you can see https://github.com/kilobtye/potrace/blob/master/potrace.js#L154. Where exactly is the exception thrown ? Btw the `unhandled promise rejection` seems to be an artefact of the way you call your `changeLogo` function as the code seems to be synchronous. Is this the case ?

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I looked through the code and could not find any promises and IE did not give any information about the error. As annoying this error is, it only happens in IE en the code strangly appears to work. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [potrace online demo](https://github.com/kilobtye/potrace), it seems that when we use this plugin, we could only use the loadImageFromFile() and loadImageFromUrl() method to load image, instead of using the base64 string.